# Odd REST API result

Tags: rest, apiv4, sub-types

I am using civicrm on drupal 7. I have configured my Civi instance to accept external REST API calls with authentication.

I want to get all the values from a set of custom fields associated with an organization sub-type.

I am making a call something like this:

```
$contacts = civicrm_api4('Contact', 'get', [
  'select' => [
    'id', 
    'display_name', 
    'my_custom_field_set.*',
  ],
  'join' => [
    ['my_custom_field_set AS my_custom_field_set', 'LEFT'],
  ],
  'where' => [
    ['my_custom_field_set.name', 'IS NOT NULL'], 
    ['contact_type', '=', 'Organization'], 
    ['contact_sub_type', '=', 'CLC'],
  ],
]);
```

This mostly works... except for 5 entries in my database that get skipped. The five failures are all part of another sub-type: `ICT Program Client` which has some other fields and relationships associated with it.

If I remove the sub-type `CLC` WHERE constraint it works. But I would prefer to understand why the presence of the other sub-type on a contact would make the query fail.

The 5 failures are definitely of sub-type `CLC`.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try with a LIKE 'CLC' rather than '='? This might help as the contact_sub_types are stored with the weird CRM_Core_DAO::VALUE_SEPARATOR around the values?

Comment: That didn't work, but changing the constraint to "CONTAINS" worked! I guess CIVI must store sub-types as a list of some kind?

Comment: Yes, a contact can have more than 1 sub type and it is stored in 1 field with the mentioned CRM_Core_DAO::VALUE_SEPARATOR in between.